# Permanently editing the Apache config file (httpd.conf) for customization of HTTP headers

Tags: apache

I am adding some headers (cache: no store and pragma) in the Apache config file i.e httpd.conf. I am getting the desired output BUT the problem is that this file (httpd.conf) is not present in our source code. I think it fetches it values from some other file or some method.

1.)I just want to know IF it(httpd.conf) is fetching its values from some other, How can i find that file?

or

2.) If there is other method by which i can permanently add those headers in my httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of Apache; if it's Apache2 then have a look at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which should contain something similar to this:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf
```

You can see that the old style httpd.conf is now split into separate files, the main one being loaded by Apache2 now being apache2.conf - so the answer is yes and yes if this is how your Apache configuration files structure works (the example given is for Apache2 on a Ubuntu 12.04 server).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what version of Apache; if it's Apache2 then have a look at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf which should contain something similar to this: